# UPDATE users SET password = crypt(password, gen_salt("bf", 8)) эквивалентная запись в MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Прохожу видео курс по Java(знаю многие против видео курсов), и там используется **PostgreSQL**.

Интересует как будет выглядеть эта запись

```
UPDATE users SET password = crypt(password, gen_salt("bf", 8));
```

в **MySQL**?

Читал, что есть `encrypt()`  в **MySQL** для этого, но не понял как сделать такую запись в **MySQL**.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!)

Comment: Странный запрос. Он предполагает, что в какой-то времени в базе лежит нешифрованный пароль? Почему бы не делать это средствами Java и не зависеть от криптографических возможностей СУБД?

Comment: Просто хотел зашифровать БД с помощью встроенных возможностей БД.